# How to block all the events when the animation is not yet finished in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want users can't do anything when the animation is not yet finished. For example: can't drag it again.

Here is my javascript source code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
        var top_ = $(".drag").position().top ;
        $(".drag").draggable({
        containment : "#box" ,
        stop: function(){
            $(this).stop(true,false).animate({
                top : top_ , 
                width : '100%'
            },1500,'easeOutCirc');
        },
        drag: function(event, ui){
            $(this).stop()
                        .css( "width", (100 - (ui.position.top / 10 ) + '%' ))
                        .css('float' , 'right');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id = "box" style= "width : 100% ; height :500px">
        <div class = "drag" style= "border: 2px solid ; width : 100% ; height : 30px">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/apss/CzkBu/102/

How to solve?

Comment: you want to prevent that drag function?

Comment: Possible to use revert? https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#revert

Comment: i want my web site be block during the animated time

Comment: Increast the speed by reducing the time, Don't give the chance to catch it again. $(".drag").draggable({
  containment : "#box" ,
  stop: function(){
   $(this).stop(true,false).animate({
    top : top_ , 
    width : '100%'
   },500,'easeOutCirc');
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop dragging following way while animating:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {    
        var top_ = $(".drag").position().top ;
    
        $(".drag").draggable({
        containment : "#box" ,
        stop: function(){
            $(this).stop(true,false).animate({
                top : top_ , 
                width : '100%'
            },1500, function() {$('.drag').draggable('enable');});
            $('.drag').draggable( 'disable' );
            
        },
        drag: function(event, ui){
            $(this).stop()
                        .css( "width", (100 - (ui.position.top / 10 ) + '%' ))
                        .css('float' , 'right');
        }
    });    
 });
```

Check [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/CzkBu/105/).

After that you can start dragging `$('.drag').draggable( 'enable' );` after animation finished.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Which leads to disable the drag gable permanently after first time